# C# XmlNodeReader exception NodeType not supported

Tags: c#, xml, exception

I'm getting the exception that NodeType "None" is not supported when trying to run the following code.

```
public int ObjectContentI(string XmlPath)
{
    XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(this.xmlr.SelectSingleNode(XmlPath));
    return xnr.ReadElementContentAsInt();
}
```

this.xmlr is a XmlDocument with a document successfully loaded in it. XmlPath contains a valid XPath url.

How do i set the NodeType (xnr.NodeType is readonly) or am I doing something else wrong?

Part of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ship weapons="0">
  <cost>
    <metal>250</metal>
    <crystal>100</crystal>
  </cost>
  <health>
    <shields>750</shields>
    <sregene>10</sregene>
    <hitpoints>1000</hitpoints>
    <oxygen cps="2">25000</oxygen>
  </health>
```

My XPath: "/ship/health/shields/text()"

Comment: Whilst not an answer I'd like to recommend that if your solution allows it I'd strongly recommend looking at LINQ to XML.  It removes pretty much all of the pain points when working with Xml in .Net

Comment: Setting the NodeType doesn't make sense because doing so would involve altering the underlying XML (and this is a *reader*, not a writer). I'm guessing the exception arises because you are trying to read the value of a node that has no inner text (self-closed?), though I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Can you post the XPath string, because the error you are getting means that you are returning a XmlNodeType of None, which most likely is due to the XPath not being correct. Also post a portion of the XML to make it easier to figure out the proper XPath

Comment: Posted the xpath and part of the xml into the initial post.

Comment: @Cameron: Reading a self-closing element won't raise a "NodeType not supported" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your approach is correct but not completely.

Let's suppose

```
XmlNode n = myXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ship/health/shields/");
```

`n.InnerXML` OR `n.InnerText` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Though conqenator provided you with code that fixed your problem following is reasoning why it didn't work in the first place:

If you don't call the Read method on a XmlNodeReader or any of the classes that derive from XmlReader, you will always get a XmlNodeType.None NodeType, which is the reason for the error. To fix the code you provided and to get an int back this is what the code needs to look like:

```
public int ObjectContentI(string XmlPath)
{
    int result;
    using(XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(this.xmlr.SelectSingleNode(XmlPath))){
        while(xnr.Read()){
            result = xnr.ReadElementContentAsInt();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that the XPath to get this wroking needs to change to `/ship/health/shields` since `ReadElementContentAsInt()` returns the content of the element and won't work on a Text Node, which what you get when using `/ship/health/shields/text()`.

Notice that I have also wrapped the XmlNodeReader in a using block, which will dispose of the XmlNodeReader once you are done with it to free up resources.